# C# Find best matching element / Simplify query to List

Tags: c#, linq

I ask myself how I can simplify something like this

```
var myList = new List<MyObject>
pulic MyObject FindBestMatching(int Prop1Value, int Prop2Value, int Prop3Value)
{
    MyObject item = null;
    item = myList.Find(x => x.Prop1 == Prop1Value && x.Prop2 == Prop2Value && x.Prop3 == Prop3Value);
    if(item != null)
    {
         return item;
    }
    item = myList.Find(x => x.Prop1 == Prop1Value && x.Prop2 == Prop2Value);
    if(item != null)
    {
         return item;
    }
    item = myList.Find(x => x.Prop1 == Prop1Value);
    // Doesn't matter if its null
    return item;
}
```

I'm sure LINQ offers a solution, but I'm not able to find it :)

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think there´s an easier appraoch? You could use `FirstOrDefault`, but you´ll need the null-checks anyway. I think your solution already is best one, at least it is readable and unserstandable and *that´s*  what actually matters - at least to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can simplify the current code into

```
  pulic MyObject FindBestMatching(int Prop1Value, int Prop2Value, int Prop3Value) {
    return 
         myList.Find(x => x.Prop1 == Prop1Value && x.Prop2 == Prop2Value && x.Prop3 == Prop3Value)
      ?? myList.Find(x => x.Prop1 == Prop1Value && x.Prop2 == Prop2Value)
      ?? myList.Find(x => x.Prop1 == Prop1Value);    
  }
```

But doing `Find` (scaning the *entire list*) can be a costly operation, if it's your case you can find the best match in one loop only:

```
  public MyObject FindBestMatching(int Prop1Value, int Prop2Value, int Prop3Value) {
    MyObject result1 = null;
    MyObject result2 = null;

    foreach (MyObject item in myList) {
      if (item.Prop1 == Prop1Value) {
        result1 = item;

        if (item.Prop2 == Prop2Value) {
          result2 = item;

          if (item.Prop3 == Prop3Value) 
            return item; 
        }
      }  
    }

    return result2 ?? result1; 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One hint: I think there is a { missing after if (x.Prop1 == Prop1Value)

Comment: @ErWu: You're right, it should be `{` after `if (item.Prop1 == Prop1Value)`. I'm sorry for the typo. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public MyObject FindBestMatching(int Prop1Value, int Prop2Value, int Prop3Value)
{
    return myList.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.Prop1 == Prop1Value && x.Prop2 == Prop2Value && x.Prop3 == Prop3Value)
    || (x.Prop1 == Prop1Value && x.Prop2 == Prop2Value)
    || (x => x.Prop1 == Prop1Value));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just finds the first element where one of the conditions is true